# How to synchronize NDB Search Index with datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

When I originally wrote the `delete` method for our data store I messed up and forgot to delete entity ids from the `search.Index`. Now I'm finding that search results are bring back `doc_ids` but there is no associate data in the datastore.

I want to iterate through all indexed documents and remove the ones that do not have associated data.

I'm thinking I can do something like this:

```py
docs = videos.Index.search('').results
doc_ids = [x.doc_id for x in docs]
keys = [ndb.Key(urlsafe=x) for x in doc_ids]
entities = [key.get() for key in keys]

nones = []
for idx, i, in enumerate(entities):
  if i == None: nones.append(idx)

for i in nones:
  videos.Index.delete(doc_ids[i])
```

I'm wondering if there is a `sync` method or something I'm missing? Also that `videos.Index.search('')` is definitely not correct because I think it is returning the same entity multiple times for ever field it matches on the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a programming standpoint, the easiest way to ensure everything is in sync WHEN YOU KNOW THINGS ARE OUT OF SYNC (I wouldn't recommend this unless you knew things were out of sync) is to delete all of the docs, and re-put them with what's currently in the datastore. You can do list puts for documents, just like the datastore, which will make this procedure more efficient. This is the best way to guarantee synchronization.

If you forgot to delete some docs, that could mean you forgot to update some docs as well on datastore updates which is why I recommend this...

Comment: I like this solution the best. It's been a while since I've been on this project so I'd forgotten to mark one as correct. But I think this is the best/cleanest way to synchronize

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Index.search you can use Index.get_range to iterate over indexed documents. More info here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass#Index_get_range

Answer (score 0):

In my datastore, I am able to retrieve the relevant data by using the docId.
I am using something like the below code to achieve the task of checking all search index entries and removing unnecessary ones:

```
docIndex = search.Index(name=[your_index_name])
docIds = [d.doc_id for d in docIndex.get_range(limit=200, ids_only=True)]
for docId in docIds:
    if !:# Check if docId refers to valid data
        docIndex.delete(docId)
```

If you had more that 200 entries in the search index, you would have to iterate the get_range call, passing the last doc_id to the next call as the start_id parameter.